# Getting a Return Value From Google Maps Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get a location name according to a lat-long coordinate from the Google maps geocoder. I cannot seem to extract the value from the geocoder callback. Here is my code:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "";
var lat = 54.1234;
var lng = -114.1234;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng } , function(results,status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        address = results[1].formatted_address; //want to get this address
    } else {
        address = 'error';
    }
});

window.alert(address) 
//address is an empty string here, but I want the value from inside the geocoder
//want access to address here to do other operations with it
```

The documentation for geocoder on the Google Developers site is almost non existant,
and I am having problems trying to find an example that is similar. I am out of my comfort area here, so any help
would be great!

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you need to _use_ the value inside the callback routine when/where its value is available.

Answer (score 1):

The call is asynchronous, so the value exists inside the callback function:

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng } , function(results,status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    address = results[1].formatted_address; //want to get this address
  } else {
    address = 'error';
  }
  window.alert(address);
});

// The code here runs before the callback function
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I want to have access to the address outside of the callback so I can do operations on it.

Comment: @Elias: You can't do that. The value doesn't exist yet when you are outside the callback. The callback can't run until you have exited the function that contains the `geocode` call.